# Implementing a voting simple voting sytem in vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to develop a voting system in vuejs . I created the mechanism to fill the stars and count it by filling the star or not when hovering or clicking on the star, but it doesn't work.

**vue component**

```
<template>
   <h2>Voting system</h2>
<div>
  <span class="fas fa-star" data-star="1"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" data-star="2"></span>
  <span class="fas fa-star" data-star="3"></span>
  <span class="fas fa-star" data-star="4"></span>
  <span class="fas fa-star" data-star="5"></span>
  &nbsp; rating: <span class="rating">-</span>
</div>
</template>
<script>
   export default {
     name: "MyVotingSystem",
     data () {
       return {
         allStar:undefined,
         mystar:undefined
       }
     },
     computed:{
     },
     methods: {
       vote() {
         this.allStar = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-star");
         this.mystar = document.querySelector(".rating");
         const rating = document.querySelector(".rating");
         this.allStar.forEach((star) => {
             star.addEventListener("click", saveRating);
             star.addEventListener("mouseover", addCSS);
             star.addEventListener("mouseleave", removeCSS);
           });
       },
       saveRating(e) {
      removeEventListenersToAllStars();
      rating.innerText = e.target.dataset.star;
      this.mystar = rating.innerText
      },
      removeEventListenersToAllStars() {
        this.allStar.forEach((star) => {
       star.removeEventListener("click", saveRating);
       star.removeEventListener("mouseover", addCSS);
       star.removeEventListener("mouseleave", removeCSS);
       });
      },
     addCSS(e, css = "checked") {
       const overedStar = e.target;
       overedStar.classList.add(css);
       const previousSiblings = getPreviousSiblings(overedStar);
       console.log("previousSiblings", previousSiblings);
       previousSiblings.forEach((elem) => elem.classList.add(css));
       },
      removeCSS(e, css = "checked") {
        const overedStar = e.target;
        overedStar.classList.remove(css);
        const previousSiblings = getPreviousSiblings(overedStar);
        previousSiblings.forEach((elem) => elem.classList.remove(css));
          },
         getPreviousSiblings(elem) {
            console.log("elem.previousSibling", elem.previousSibling);
            let sibs = [];
            const spanNodeType = 1;
           while ((elem = elem.previousSibling)) {
                if (elem.nodeType === spanNodeType) {
               sibs = [elem, ...sibs];
                  }
           }
              return sibs;
       }
     }
   }
</script>
<style>
     .checked {
        color: orange;
     }
</style>
```

At the level of the console of my browser, I have no error on my code.
When I click on a star or I hover nothing happens and does not count the number of votes 1 if I click the first star, two if I click the second star and so on

Do you have an idea?

Comment: The idea is that you don't have to directly access DOM in Vue without a good reason (here there's none). You ended up with unnecessarily complicated and error-prone code that is hard to figure out.

Comment: hi @Estus Flask , I just want to activate the count when a star is clicked and get the value 1 if it is clicked or hovered on the first star and the same for the others.
If you can do it simply, can you show me a code example please

Comment: It's supposed to be done this way, https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#listening-to-events and https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes , with zero querySelector and addEventListener in the code.

Comment: hi @Estus Flask, Can you adapt it with my example please so I can see. It is not too clear, I am a beginner in vuejs

Comment: SO is question and answer, not code writing service. If you have specific problems with current attempt, consider updating the question, this way it's more likely it'll be solved

Comment: I can suggest you a better way to do it: Only use hover event on each start item. When you hover any star you have the star position soy you can manually change de previous icons. If you hover the 4th icon you make a loop to change all icons staring from 4 to 1.